# sed - inserting point and slash with escaping

Tags: insert, sed, escaping, character

Im trying to sed insert:

```
M3_tmp="$(echo $M3 | sed 's/\./\\\/g')"
```

but I can't find a solution

I have this string:

```
sub.domain.com
```

and want to add backslashes before every point like this:

```
sub\.domain\.com
```

Can anybody help me? thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
M3_tmp=$(echo $M3 | sed 's/\./\\./g')
```

Answer (score 2):

Too many backslashes, missing dot:

```
echo $M3 | sed 's/\./\\./g'
```

If you are using bash, you can use parameter expansion:

```
echo ${M3//./\\.}
```